# how to use sampling frequency in FFT and Morlet wavelet in numpy in python

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing, fft, wavelet

So I have been playing around with some [raw biosignal data](https://github.com/KooshaS/EEG-Dataset) and trying to learn python for signal processing and feature extraction.

I have couple of questions regarding numpy specific question related with FFT and construction of morlet wavelet.

**FFT** : I have a signal stored in a CSV file with 80608 data points. It contains all raw 1D data. If that matters, the signal acquired from the sensor at 256 samples per second.

My question related to FFT are -

1. Should I apply FFT on the entire signal ?

```
data = pd.read_csv('12-01-2016.csv')
signal = data['Electrode']  
samplingRate = len(signal) # 80608 

L = np.arange(1,np.floor(samplingRate/2),dtype='int') 

fhat = np.fft.fft(signal,samplingRate)
PSD = fhat*np.conj(fhat)/samplingRate

plt.plot(PSD[L],color='r',LineWidth=2,label="FFT of noisy signal") 
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

2. Or Should I apply FFT on 256 data points first and then next 256 data points and so on for the entire signal without overlapping or should I use sliding window? So question related with this section is, if I pass signal as entire signal and samplingRate as 256 instead of full length of the signal in the FFT method, would it calculate the FFT of entire signal without requiring loop or just for the first 256 sample? Do I have to use for loop to do the FFT on 256 points in each loop?.

```
fhat = np.fft.fft(signal,samplingRate)
```

3. What I am trying to do here is to create a morlet wavelet and apply FFT on it to convert it into Frequency domain. Once done, I would multiply point by point in frequency domain - signalFFT*morletFFT (point by point) and apply inverse FFT to get back the filtered signal. so I have two question here

   a.  when I create morlet wavelet by multiplying sine wave and gaussian, how do I choose the freqency (f)? Does this frequency defines the frequency which gets filtered out?

   b. how do you choose window for the steps for creating morlet wavelet as I have defined here as -1 and 1 in steps = np.linespace()?

```
# creating a morlet wavelet
steps = np.linspace(-1,1,samplingRate) 
f = 150 # frequency 
s = 7/(2*np.pi*f) # this is the standard deviation of the gaussain

c_signal = np.cos(2*np.pi*f*steps) 
plt.plot(c_signal,color='r',LineWidth=2,label="Sine wave ") 
plt.legend()
plt.show()

gausian_win = np.exp(-(pow(steps, 2))/(2*pow(s,2)))
plt.plot(gausian_win,color='r',LineWidth=2,label="Gaussian window") 
plt.legend()
plt.show()

morlet = np.multiply(c_signal,gausian_win)

plt.plot(morlet,color='r',LineWidth=2,label="Morlet Wavelet") 
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The idea of the whole exercise is to extract ECG artifacts, if present in the signal. A quick google search tells me that it is somewhere between 100-150hz **window** so I assume I would need a wavelet which works as a bandpass filter to zero out all the frequecies except this range 100-150Hz. Why I am trying to wavelet transform like this because I have read doing this way is more efficient computationally than doing wavelet transform directly becuasee FFT is really really Fast.

Another question is, how do I go about it applying it on real time data instead of static data?

Thank you.

P.S. Am I doing it correctly? Am I doing anything wrong? Big am I asking too much because I am dumb?
P.S.S I will update the question as I get more clarity on this subject. If you want I can share my notebook.